# Execute shell script from android studio

Tags: java, bash, shell, android-studio

I'm writing some tests in Android Studio with Robotium. In my test file I'd like to execute a shell script that prepares the right environment on our server. I don't work in Java/AndroidStudio so this is completely new territory. Is it possible to execute a shell script?

I found some code, but java doesn't recognize `commandLine`

`commandLine 'sh', './myScript.sh'`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myshellScript.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");` will do the trick